# Migrating django models in Postgres/PostGIS not reflecting

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I successfully imported my Geojson data using ogr2ogr to PostGIS.

I run the following command: `python manage.py inspectdb`

```
class Route(models.Model):
   ogc_fid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   distance = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
   route_type = models.CharField(max_length=-1, blank=True, null=True)
   route_long = models.CharField(max_length=-1, blank=True, null=True)
   route_name = models.CharField(max_length=-1, blank=True, null=True)
   agency_id = models.ForeignKey(max_length=-1, blank=True, null=True)
   route_id = models.CharField(max_length=-1, blank=True, null=True)
   route_url = models.CharField(max_length=-1, blank=True, null=True)
   route_desc = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
   duration = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
   shape_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
   route_tcolor = models.CharField(max_length=-1, blank=True, null=True)
   route_color = models.CharField(max_length=-1, blank=True, null=True)
   wkb_geometry = models.LineStringField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'network_route'
```

Of course, I had to modify the `max_length` to a positive integer and set `manage` to `True` so I did.

I also added an additional column, `created_at` and `updated_at`.

Resulting to the following final model:

```
class Route(models.Model):
   ogc_fid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   distance = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
   route_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
   route_long = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
   route_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
   agency_id = models.ForeignKey(Agency, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   route_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
   route_url = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
   route_desc = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
   duration = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
   shape_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
   route_tcolor = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
   route_color = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
   wkb_geometry = models.LineStringField(blank=True, null=True)

   created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now(),editable=False)
   updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

   objects = models.GeoManager()

class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'network_route'

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #On save, update timestamps
    if not self.id:
        self.created_at = timezone.now()
    self.updated_at = timezone.now()
    return super(Route, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
    return self.route_id
```

I run: `makemigrations [appname]` and it only detects the changes in `Meta` `- Change Meta options on route`

How can I add additional changes in the model such as the `created_at` and `updated_at` be caught by the migration?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to renovate some legacy code? Do you have a database that you must preserve?

Comment: @JohnMoutafis well, yes. but actually I can redo it all since I'm still setting it up. however, my problem lies if for example along the way I need to add another field in my model, how can I prevent something such as redoing it all over again?

Comment: Hey, @Reiion I was wondering, was my answer helpful? Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @JohnMoutafis hey! sorry I 'm actually going to try it now. I am just able to get back to it today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem must have occurred from that line in your legacy code: `managed = False`. There are some options though on how to solve your problem:

1. **The easy (clean slate) way:**

   Since you can rebuild your database and you don't have anything that you can't live without, erase everything and do it over.

   - Erase everything except `__init__.py` in your migrations folder.
   - Erase your database and remake it.
   - `./manage.py makemigrations`.
   - `./manage.py migrate`.

   Well, you will lose everything but this is the "clean slate" approach.
2. **The (probably) better way:**

   Open up your last migration (the one made with the `makemigrations` command) and write the rest by hand:

   ```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
   from __future__ import unicode_literals

   import django.utils.timezone
   from django.db import migrations, models


   class Migration(migrations.Migration):
       dependencies = [
           ('your_app', 'your_previous_migration'),
       ]

       operations = [
           # That takes care of you Meta changes 
           migrations.AlterModelOptions(
               name='route',
               options={
                   'managed': True, 
                   'table': 'network_route', 
               },
           ),
           # That will add the created_at field
           migrations.AddField(
               model_name='route',
               name='created_at',
               field=models.DateTimeField(
                   default=django.utils.timezone.now,
                   editable=False
               ),
           ),
           # That will add the updated_at field
           migrations.AddField(
               model_name='route',
               name='updated_at',
               field=models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True),
      ]
   ```

   Now you can try `./manage.py migrate` with that migration which should do the trick!

Comment: I tried the first one. and the second one looks viable as well. But adding new fields in the models, I had to edit it always. If I delete a field it would reflect though. So that's actually my problem. :(